# Jquery drag and drop image in an iframe and open modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, iframe

i tried an example:

> https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/droppable/photo-manager.html

for jquery image Drag and Drop into an iframe; i want a small help regarding when an image is dropped into the iframe at that point of time on mouse release event i want to show a modal popup containing a simple form with simple fields.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks